# Alternative for google location autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, web, geolocation

I am currently using ngAutocomplete on a project, https://github.com/wpalahnuk/ngAutocomplete, which is a fantastic plugin.

I now have an issue with moving into China that I can't use Google's API in order to populate the data.

Is there any alternatives for this? essentially all I need is a JSON list of locations along with the long & lat of the location for my app.

Answer (score 0):

Had a suggestion from @dnewns regarding this and just pointing it to my server and doing it server side so the solution has been as follows:

Endpoint to call off to my own API, have an endpoint will then call off to https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/autocomplete

When I get this back, I can then call off to https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search to get my long/lat for the location